# Live Preview Button missing

Tags: editor

I upgraded to Craft 2.1 and there is no Preview Button visible.

It must have something to do with the configuration I created for the different sections because when I use the same craft installation with a clean database the preview button is visible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the Live Preview button to show up, two criteria must be met:

- Your section’s *“Entries in this section have their own URLs”* setting must be checked
- Your section’s *“Entry Template”* setting must be set to a **valid** template path
- For Craft 3.2+ pro version, a preview target must be specified. This happens automatically, but might be missing [due to a bug](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/5844). Add a preview target with Primary entry page => {url} to fix this.

Make sure both of those are set correctly, and the Live Preview button will show up.

Comment: Also, an empty value for the Entry Template is a valid value. I was trying to remove Live Preview and it took me way too long to realize that. Using some gibberish removed it, though.

Answer (score 3):

Have you specified a template to use under that section's settings?  If you didn't,  the Live Preview button won't show.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue of the Live Preview button not displaying. 
I followed the instructions from Brandon and Brad and still did not see the live preview button.
**It was not till that I created the template in the template directory that the live preview button appeared**.

I am using Craft Pro 2.5.2759, installed on my local machine with MAMP.

I hope this helps others coming to this page with the same issue.

Comment: This is of course expected behaviour with Craft and is completely un-dependant on the version of Craft or using MAMP. How can Craft create a live preview of a page that doesn't have a template? How would it know what fields to use, how would it know where to put those fields, what would the fields look like? ☺

Comment: I just assumed that CraftCMS would have thrown a 404 error or something. Usually, as I create channels I also create templates but today I was setting up a test site and skipped setting up templates. I thought Craft was broken after updating since I have always seen the Live Preview button. I like the fact that the button does not appear till everything is setup for the live preview feature to properly work.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. However, I had valid URLs and templates, as I used the same setup for other news sections on the site.

I resorted to creating a new section for the entries with the same details as the previous (had to change the details of the original one first) then, in the database I changed the section IDs in the entries to move them to the new section I created.

This fixed the odd issue I had, where everything looked fine but didn't work.